# Is there a selection tool that will select everything towards the cursor?

Tags: selection-tools

So the tool I'm looking for is basically something that I would expect to see in the ***Select Menu*** but I'm not sure it's there or where else to look.

Basically, something like the following-> Select a loop, then everything else towards the 3D cursor.

Here is a visual.[image]

Maybe there is python script that someone is aware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there exists any selection tool that uses the 3d cursor in this manner but there are a few that work in a similar way.

There is *Select > Side of Active*.

> Selects all data on the mesh in a single axis

If you select at least a vertex or an edge, it will select all the faces to the positive (right) or negative (left) axis mode of that selection based on the axis you choose in the operator settings. You can also of course just invert the selection to get the other side.

There is also *Select > Loop Inner-Region*.

> Converts a closed selection of edges to the region of faces it encloses

I would say this is almost the opposite of select side of active. Depending on where you select, it will select all faces to the side that has the lesser amount of faces to the end of the mesh.

Comment: Never knew about side of active, thanks :) You can change the axis used + - etc. in the redo panel (F6 panel).

Comment: I just noticed that the tool options stay active even if you make more selections in the 3D Viewport.  This is the only mesh tool in Blender I'm aware of that can do this.  I hope that becomes more standard.

Comment: @MarcClintDion It is just working with selections and not actually modifying the mesh, there is nothing to apply etc.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any tool which selects based on the 3D cursor, however *3D view > Select > [Select loop inner-region](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Selecting/Advanced#Loop_Inner-Region)* does pretty much does the equivalent.

[image]

[image]

It selects the side with the least geometry, so if that's not the side you want, invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, or enable *Select bigger* in the redo panel immediately after running the operator (<kbd>F6</kbd>) or at the bottom of the tool shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>).

I think this tool was originally designed to select boundary loops which formed a ring like this, which might make the behavior of this tool appear more clear/intuitive:

[image]

Note that you can use *select boundary loop* to select the ring around the selection (the exact opposite behavior of *select loop inner region*). See the above gif.

---

There are only two possible selections based on such a boundary loop (one side or the other side), so IMO using the cursor is probably overkill.

Comment: Note that there is a [bug](https://developer.blender.org/T40309) with *select bigger* with equally sized regions, so you might just want to use invert.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for but I had to mark iKlsR's answer as correct just because it does all this and more from the look of it.  Cheers